# Don't let user add an element if already present (even if marked as setDeleted)

Tags: breeze, durandal

I work with Breeze in my asp.net project.

I have an entity (transport) which contains another entity (linkedTransports).

I have a page where I allows users to add/delete some linkedTransports for my Transport. When user click on the delete button for a specific linkedTransport it is marked as Deleted but this is really deleted only when calling `datacontext.saveChanges();`. User can still hit cancel and then I call `datacontext.cancelChanges()`.

Each linkedTransport must be unique. I mean I cannot add twice the element 123.

Each time a user try to add a linkedTransport, I loop through all linkedTransports and check if this is not already present. For most scenarios it works pretty well.

**My problem**: the case below is problematic:

- deleted the element 123
- (the delete is not commit until saveChanges)
- add the element 123

Because the element is deleted (in fact setDeleted but not committed server side) i didn't detect his presence client side and then the add falls in error because the key is already present.

I hope you see what I mean.

Any idea how to loop through all linkedTransports (even deleted) to check if it already exists BEFORE allowing user the add it?

Here are my classes:

```
public class Transport
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual List<LinkedTransport> LinkedTransports { get; set; }
}

public class LinkedTransport
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int TransportId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int TransportRelatedId { get; set; }

    public virtual Transport Transport { get; set; }
    public virtual Transport TransportRelated { get; set; }
}
```

So far here is what I do to check if an element already exists:

```
// don't accept if selected element is already present
for (var i = transport().linkedTransports().length - 1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
    if (transport().linkedTransports()[i].transportRelatedId() == transpRelatedId) {
        alert('Already present!');
        return false;
    }
};

// if we go so far then we can create the linkedTransport safely
ctxTransport.createLinkedTransport(transpId, transpRelatedId, transpNumber);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that I might supplement the search list with deleted transports, e.g.,

```
var transports = transport().linkedTransports();
for (var i = transports.length; i-- >= 0){
    if (transports[i].RelatedTransportId() == transpRelatedId) {
        alert('Already present!');
        return false;
    }
}

var deleted = manager.getEntities(transportType, breeze.EntityState.Deleted);
for (i = deleted.length; i-- >= 0){
    if (deleted[i].id() == transpRelatedId) {
        alert('Was deleted!');
        return false;
    }
}
```